# Modify google app script for whole column A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a File that contains a list of Google Drive File's IDs in column A. In column B I have emails. And column C a list of roles (you know when you share a google sheet with someone)

So I have many rows that contain different file IDs, emails and roles. And I need to assign the email and role in that row to file's ID of that row.
I have found a great script (credit to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4179ndy_AM) to give access automatically, But it works in such a way, that it only gives access to the first ID in Column A to all the emails in Column B.

Can you modify my script for my goal?

**Here is the script:**

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Share")
  .addItem("Give Access", "shareFile")
  .addToUi();
}

function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const fileId = sheet.getRange(2, 1).getvalue();
  const emailAndPermissions = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  const fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileI[enter image description here][1]d);

  emailAndPermissions.forEach(function(emailAndPermissions) {
    if(emailAndPermissions[1] === "Viewer") {
      fileToShare.addViewer(emailAndPermissions[0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermissions[1] === "Commenter") {
      fileToShare.addCommenter(emailAndPermissions[0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermissions[1] === "Editor") {
      fileToShare.addEditor(emailAndPermissions[0]);
  }
  else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Check the input")
  }
  });
}
```

**Screenshot of sheet**

[image: 1]

Comment: Kindly credit the author of the script. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your script is only sharing to the first ID is because on the line `const fileId = sheet.getRange(2, 1).getvalue();` you are only getting the first ID. So you need to modify this to `getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues()` so it will get all the IDs from your Column A.

I just use `.flat()` to flatten the array since the data from sheets is structured as nested array. Then from here you can loop through this to check the permission on column C, and share it with the email in the Column B.

I have modified your script to do this.

**Try:**

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Share")
  .addItem("Give Access", "shareFile")
  .addToUi();
}


function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const fileId = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat();
  const emailAndPermissions = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

  for (i = 0; i < fileId.length; i++) {

    var fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId[i]);

    if (emailAndPermissions[i][1] === "Viewer") {
      fileToShare.addViewer(emailAndPermissions[i][0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermissions[i][1] === "Commenter") {
      fileToShare.addCommenter(emailAndPermissions[i][0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermissions[i][1] === "Editor") {
      fileToShare.addEditor(emailAndPermissions[i][0]);
    }
    else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Check the input")
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Just tested it with different emails and it works.
Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi, Dan F!
It totally works ;) Thank you!

Maybe you also can add here a function to take access back when this person copied the file to his/her Google Drive?

Comment: @Bohdan Apologies we don't normally code for you. You may ask that in a new post and show some things/steps that you've done towards it that way the community is more likely to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose this modification:

```
function shareFiles() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (let [id,email,role] of data) {
    try {
      let file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      switch (role) {
        case ("Viewer"):    file.addViewer(email); break;
        case ("Commenter"): file.addCommenter(email); break;
        case ("Editor"):    file.addEditor(email); break;
      }
    }
    catch(err) { console.log(err) }
  }
}
```